# How do I save query results into a separate table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, save

I have a database that allows the user to query for books in the database.

I am trying to save the query result as a "bookmark."  The user enters a query and is then able to click on a result to see detailed information for that particular book.

Then there is a menu option to allow the user to "save" the query to their bookmarks. The saved query is inserted into a database table. Bookmarks is a activity that loads the saved data as a list view allowing the user to manage their bookmarks.

Everything is set up and working wonderfully except for the saving.  I do not know how, or what would be the best way to get the results from the query into the database when the saved menu option is picked.

A standard sqlite insert works, but does not have the specific query result data with it.

Some of the code:

```
package com.example.newdatabase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DetailView extends Activity
{
    private DBAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private long rowid;//row for book from position in database
    public static final String BOOKM_ID = "rowid";

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.detailviewlist);

  rowid=getIntent().getExtras().getLong(TitleSearch.ROW_ID);//passed from TitleSearch pass the row id

        dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        //loads data into list 
        displayListView();
   }

private void displayListView()
{
    Cursor cursor=dbHelper.getABOOK(rowid);//cursor and query method only shows one book

    //defines columns to bind
    String [] columns =new String[]
            {
                DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
                DBAdapter.KEY_AUTHOR,
                DBAdapter.KEY_EDITION,
                DBAdapter.KEY_PUBLISHER,
                DBAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                DBAdapter.KEY_OPAC,
                DBAdapter.KEY_LOCATION,
                DBAdapter.KEY_CALL,
                DBAdapter.KEY_COPIES,
                DBAdapter.KEY_STATUS,

            };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] 
      {
        R.id.title,
        R.id.author,
        R.id.edition,
        R.id.publisher,
        R.id.description,
        R.id.subject,
        R.id.location,
        R.id.callnum,
        R.id.copies,
        R.id.status,
      };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
      //as well as the layout information
      dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.detailbook,
       cursor,
       columns,
        to,
        0);

     ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
      // Assign adapter to ListView
      listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) //save menu
    {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.savemenu, menu);
       return true;

    }



  /* @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) //lauches the bookmark when saved
    {
       Intent addContact = new Intent(DetailView.this, Bookmark.class);
       startActivity(addContact);
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/


   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)//menu action
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.addsave:
            // Single menu item is selected to save book info

            //adds info into bookmark on save click

            //this is where i am having an issue





            Toast.makeText(DetailView.this, "The book has been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//feedback for user
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    } //end of options
    }//end of detail view
```

I am trying the save the results from getABOOK(rowid) query into the database table that Bookmarks uses.

Unless there is a better way to save the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend having a new column called Bookmark in the same table and add the timestamp of bookmark to a particular row(s) when the user selects bookmark.

Now in the bookmark view you can simply query for all rows where bookmark is not null.

Comment: Thanks you for your response and recommendation.  I will try it and see.

Comment: Thank you again for the recommendation.  It worked very well and prevented a headache :)